# MEAN Stack Update function

Tags: angularjs, mongodb

So what I am trying to do is update from client side and update in the backend as well. I am using MEAN stack to accomplish this. Currently I can get the ID of the individual item I want to update but cannot figure out what I'm missing to update it in the database.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<h1>Sorting Books</h1>
<div ng-init="getBooks()"></div>
<p><input type="text" ng-model="test" placeholder="Search..."></p>
<p><select ng-model="category" ng-options="x for x in categoryNames">Category</select></p>
eBook: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="eBook">

<ul ng-repeat="book in allTheBooks | filter:test | filter:category | filter: eBook">
<li><strong>Title: </strong><span editable-text="book.title" e-name="name" e-form="editableForm" e-required>{{book.title}}</span></li>
<ul>
  <li><strong>Category: </strong><span editable-text="book.category" e-name="name" e-form="editableForm" e-required>{{book.category}}</span></li>
  <li><strong>eBook: </strong><span editable-text="book.eBook" e-name="name" e-form="editableForm" e-required>{{book.eBook?'Yes':'No'}}</span></li>
  <li><strong>Volume: </strong><span editable-text="book.volume" e-name="name" e-form="editableForm" e-required>{{book.volume}}</li>
  <li><strong>Author: </strong><span editable-text="book.author" e-name="name" e-form="editableForm" e-required>{{book.author}}</li>
  <li><strong>Genre: </strong><span editable-text="book.genre" e-name="name" e-form="editableForm" e-required>{{book.genre}}</li>
  <li><strong>Stars: </strong><span editable-text="book.stars" e-name="name" e-form="editableForm" e-required>{{book.stars}}</li>
  <li><strong>Comments: </strong><span editable-text="book.comments" e-name="name" e-form="editableForm" e-required>{{book.comments}}</li>
  <li><button type="button" ng-click="deleteBook(book._id)">Delete</button></li>
  <li>
    <form editable-form name="editableForm" onaftersave="saveUser()">
    <div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="editableForm.$show(); update(book._id);" ng-show="!editableForm.$visible">Edit</button>
    <span ng-show="editableForm.$visible">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="editableForm.$waiting">Save</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-disabled="editableForm.$waiting" ng-click="editableForm.$cancel()">Cancel</button>
    </span>
    </div>
    </form>
  </li>
</ul>
</ul>
```

Here is my Script.js code:

```
$scope.update = function( id ){
console.log('figuring things out... ' , id);

};//end of Update
```

Now with this I've tried multiple different things, $scope.book.title, etc. but gives the the error of 'cannot read property 'title' of undefined.'

And here is my app.js code:

```
app.put('/bookUpdate/:id', function (req, res) {
var bookId = req.params.id;
console.log('from app.js ' , bookId);
});//end of app.update function
```

I'm open to anything really, I've tried multiple different things with little to no success. Let me know if you need more clarification of the code.

Thanks in advance!

-Maykid

Comment: If you are in a loop where allTheBooks is an array and "book" is a local variable inside the ng-repeat, your update function should have as param the whole "book" object: update(book). Not just the ID. Anyway, this looks messy. Why don't you just make a different view to edit an individual record instead of this ng-repeat mess

Comment: Which version of x-editable are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing `id` to the `update` function, pass the whole `book` object:

```
$scope.update = function(book){
    var url = BASE + "/bookUpdate/" + book._id;
    $http.put(url, book).then(function onSuccess(response) {
        console.log("Success");
    }).catch(function onReject(errorResponse) {
        console.log(errorResponse.status);
        throw errorResponse;
    });
 };
```

The `ng-repeat` directive creates child scopes for each item.  The `book` object is placed on those child scopes. So use `book` as an argument to a function in `ng-click` or `ng-submit`.